# How to add attributes to SOAP envelope part, using suds?

Tags: python, suds

I have WSDL server with some methods, each methods accepts DataModelType.
Earlier I used it this way:

```
import suds.transport.http
from suds.client import Client

trans = suds.transport.http.HttpAuthenticated(username=username,
                                              password=password)
__client = Client(url, transport=trans)
func = __client.service.__getattr__("ReceiveData")
argument = __client.factory.create('DataModelType')
argument["Key"] = "0001" 
return func(argument)
```

And it perfectly worked.

It created XML with DataRequest automatically:

```
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <DataRequest>
      <DataModelType>
        <Key>0001</Key>
         <Data></Data>
      </DataModelType>
    </DataRequest>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Sent it, and as response I got something like:

```
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <DataResponse>
      <DataModelType>
        <Key>0001</Key>
        <Data>"Help me solve that magic, please"</Data>
      </DataModelType>
    </DataResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

And **return func(argument)** gave me back python object built from **DataModelType**

Now I found that tag *DataRequest* has parameters that I have to set for server to receive right response. But how should I set them pythonic throw **suds**, not exstracting XML, parsing it, and then send it by http transport?

If sending by http transport is just one way, how to do it? I'm trying to simulate what is going inside **return func(argument)**, but even if it takes exactly the same parameters, result is different.

Is there interface in suds to set properties of convert that it cares of by himself? How to solve that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
Instead of example was in question, we need to make using **func** more concrete.

```
import suds.transport.http
from suds.client import Client

trans = suds.transport.http.HttpAuthenticated(username=username,
                                              password=password)
__client = Client(url, transport=trans)
func = __client.service.__getattr__("ReceiveData")
argument = __client.factory.create('DataModelType')
argument["Key"] = "0001" 

#getting internal soap class and extracting entire soap_object:
clientclass = func.clientclass({})
SoapClient = clientclass(func.client, func.method)
binding = func.method.binding.input
soap_xml = binding.get_message(func.method, [modelthings], {})

#fix anything what we want, that is representation of all envelope that should be sent        
soap_xml.children[0].children[1].children[0].attributes.append(u'attachmentInfo="true"')
soap_xml.children[0].children[1].children[0].attributes.append(u'attachmentData="true"')
soap_xml.children[0].children[1].children[0].attributes.append(u'ignoreEmptyElements="true"')

#then prepare it as suds would do it:
SoapClient.last_sent(soap_xml)
plugins = PluginContainer(SoapClient.options.plugins)
plugins.message.marshalled(envelope=soap_xml.root())
if SoapClient.options.prettyxml:
    soap_xml = soap_xml.str()
else:
    soap_xml = soap_xml.plain()
soap_xml = soap_xml.encode('utf-8')
plugins.message.sending(envelope=soap_xml)
request = Request(SoapClient.location(), soap_xml)
request.headers = SoapClient.headers()
my_reply = SoapClient.options.transport.send(request)

ctx = plugins.message.received(reply=my_reply)
my_reply = ctx.reply
if SoapClient.options.retxml:
    answer = my_reply 
else:
    answer = SoapClient.succeeded(binding, my_reply)

return answer
```

So, we still use suds as max, as possible, but receiving access to any field of entire SOAP message.